# Way to show survey questions based off previous survey q using PHP

Tags: php

So we have a survey I'm building and for this example - lets say Q1 has 50 choices and they can pick one (radio button)

Now on Q2, we show the same 50, MINUS the one that was chosen in Q1.

My initial thought was to write a endless chain of if statements like

if  $_REQUEST['q1'] != 1 , echo the html code for the answer
if $_REQUEST ['q1'] != 2, echo the html code for answer #2

etc

As you can see that's probably way overkill , and since Q1 is a radio button, there's only going to be one answer.

I wasnt even sure how to google or search for an answer to this - so any advice or suggestions would be appreciated. I'm sure I'm missing something very easy :/

Answer (score 0):

I would store the answers in an array with keys as some sort of answer id.
For example `$answers=array(0=>"answer 1",1=>"answer 2")`

Then, propagate chosen answers in another array containing the keys (doesn't matter what the value is) with the request.

When the rendering should come up use the array_diff_key($answers,(array)$_REQUEST['chosenAnswers']) function and render the resulting array. (This function will return the difference between the two arrays based on the keys and previously chosen answers won't be in the resulting array)... You can choose to store the HTML directly in the array, or store just the answer and, when rendering, add the HTML in a while statement.

Something like this:

```
$answers=array(0=>"answer 1",1=>"answer 2",...,50=>"answer 49");
$chosen=(array)$_request['chosenAnswers'];
$result=array_diff_key($answers,$chosen);
$html="";
while ($answer = current($result)) {

    $html.="<label><input type="radio" name="grp1" value='".key($result)."'/>".$answer."</label>";

next($result);
}
echo $html;
```

I may have made some mistakes in the code, but you get the idea :)